# How to improve the inference time of the ensemble models

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

I have 10 models and want to ensemble these models together. I need to make a inference with a very very quick response time.

First I defined the containers:

```
// model containder
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<LRModel>> container;

// predictions, n_models = 10
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> pred_2d(n_models);
```

Then I use thread pools to make predictions concurrently:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < n_models; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(std::thread(&Search::make_infer, this,
                                     std::ref(container[i]),
                                     std::ref(input),
                                     std::ref(pred_2d[i])));
}
```

And the `Search::make_infer` is defined as:

```
container[i]->predict(input, pred);
```

By doing this, the response time decreased from 80ms to 40ms. But still far from satisfied. I need to reduce the time to 10ms. How can I further optimize this?

Comment: What is `input`. Other data seems to be independent for each thread (index) but this one seems to be shared. Is that data read-only and in memory? Also, in practice the performance can greatly be impacted by caching issues depending on memory access pattern so if not all data fit in first level cache, having more thread won't necessarily improve performance. So in practice, it is hard to give general advice as performance depends on a lot of factors. Also, performance might also vary depending on the number of cores, the size of caches on the CPU etc... Best thing is to profile and compare...

Comment: @Phil1970 The `input` is a `vector<string>` from a RPC request. I don't understand "if not all data fit in first level cache ..."? How can I actually put all data in first level cache?

Answer (score 1):

A general rule is measure, then measure some more, so use a tool to measure where your time goes. But there is still some things you should always look out for.

If all your data already is in memory, you should as a generel rule not make more threads than you have hardware threads and instead let each thread handle more than one search. A task switch takes from around 1000 cycles to 20000ns depending on how lucky you are.

Also creating a thread is not free, so if you cant use the extra threads in your CPU you can save a bit there, better still if you run this multiple times you can use a thread pool.

If your data is not in memory already more threads might help as some threads then can wait while other proceed processing.

Next reduce the amount of shared data, which in your case seems to be only the access to the containers. If each of your 3 `std::ref` is only accessed once it will hardly matters, but we can't see what `predict` does so there could be a problem too. If you only read from the `vector`s that there is less of a problem.

If each `predict` takes the same time and you don't have one hardware thread for each the minimum run time is

```
time = time(predict)*num_predict/num_hardware_threads
```

And your runtime is limited by the slowest software/hardware thread combination, task switching, system calls, true/false sharing etc. influence the individual runtimes.

Also why use `std::ref` at all, your data seems to be usable as references anyway.

If you don't plan on changing the input parameters you should also use a `const` version of them to pass as parameters.